# Error in checking highest datafile name while using MAX

Tags: sql, database, database-administration

I'm looking to get the highest filename present in datafile.
query:
    `select max(file_name) from dba_data_files where tablespace_name='XYZ'` ;

The above query detects only if the datafiles are from 
abc[0-9].dbf.
the query doesn't show the file abc10.dbf even though its present.
it shows abc9.dbf.
is there any other approach to get the highest filename of a datafile ?

After analyzing it for a while.
I gave order by file_name in my query.
this is the output.

```
/.../data01/odam1.dbf
/.../data01/odam10.dbf
/.../data01/odam2.dbf
....................
/../data01/odam9.dbf
```

maybe the max function detects the last filename and that's why shows odam9.dbf as output and not odam10.dbf.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the filenames that you have shown, you can order by the length and the name:

```
select file_name
from dba_data_files
where tablespace_name = 'XYZ'
order by len(filename) desc, file_name desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note:  The function for length might be `length()`, depending on the database.  And some databases spell `fetch first 1 row only` as `limit` or even `select top`.

Also, this makes the big assumption that the filenames all have the same structure, only differing in the number at the end (as in the examples in your question).

Comment: Working fine. Thank you so much